# Display post from topic I follow

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a database like this

```
**member**
id_member (int)
username (varchar)

**topic**
id_topic (int)
topic_name (varchar)

**subscribe**
id_member (int)
id_topic (int)

**post**
id_post (int)
id_topic (int)
title_post (varchar)
```

I have a timeline system to only show post from topic that I follow, I am confused about SQL Query Left Join, anyone can help me?

In the subscribe table, it shows you what topic each member follows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use join ,i haven't join members table if you have known `id_member` so just filter it and below query will give you all the posts from all the topics followed by member `DISTINCT` is used to prevent the duplication of results

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM
post p
JOIN subscribe s ON (p.id_topic =s.id_topic )
JOIN topic t ON (p.id_topic =t.id_topic )
WHERE s.id_member ='your id'
/* ORDER BY p.id_post DESC for the latest post to show first if id_post is set to  auto_increment*/
```

**EDIT** this will list all the posts which are from the articles which are not followed by member

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.* FROM
post p
JOIN
(SELECT * FROM subscribe WHERE id_topic IN (SELECT id_topic FROM topic  ) AND id_member !='your id') s
ON (p.id_topic =s.id_topic )
JOIN topic t ON (p.id_topic =t.id_topic )
WHERE s.id_member ='your id'
```

Comment: hmm, thanks so much its work well :D, but how if I would show my post in the topic that I dont follow?

Comment: In your given schema there is no directly way to relate post per member ,posts are related to topic and topic relates to member then how you posts are related to member directly ?

Comment: thanks again, but the update isn't show anything, I just wanted to show in my timeline : 
– Post from topic that I follow
- Post that I post in the topic I follow
- Post that I post but not in the topic I follow